# Spring Kafka listenerExecutor

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I'm setting up a kafka listener in a spring boot application and I can't seem to get the listener running in a pool using an executor.  Here's my kafka configuration:

```
@Bean
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor messageProcessorExecutor() {
    logger.info("Creating a message processor pool with {} threads", numThreads);
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    exec.setCorePoolSize(200);
    exec.setMaxPoolSize(200);
    exec.setKeepAliveSeconds(30);
    exec.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
    exec.setQueueCapacity(0); // Yields a SynchronousQueue
    exec.setThreadFactory(ThreadFactoryFactory.defaultNamingFactory("kafka", "processor"));
    return exec;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, PollerJob> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroup);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, PollerJob> factory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props,
            new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(PollerJob.class));
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, PollerJob> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, PollerJob> factory
            = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(Integer.valueOf(kafkaThreads));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setListenerTaskExecutor(messageProcessorExecutor());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);
    return factory;
}
```

The `ThreadFactoryFactory` used by the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` just makes sure the thread is named like `'kafka-1-processor-1'`.

The `ConsumerFactory` has the `ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG` flag set to false and I'm using manual mode for the acknowledgement which is required to use executors according to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_container_thread_naming).

My listener looks like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "my_topic",
        group = "my_group",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(@Payload SomeJob job, Acknowledgment ack) {
    ack.acknowledge();
    logger.info("Running job {}", job.getId());
    ....
}
```

Using the Admin Server I can inspect all the threads and only one `kafka-N-processor-N` threads is being created but I expected to see up to 200.  The jobs are all running one at a time on the that one thread and I can't figure out why.

How can I get this setup to run the listeners using my executor with as many threads as possible?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE and kafka 0.11.0.0.

Comment: The Spring Kafka version, please?

Comment: I've updated the question, but it's Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE and kafka 0.11.0.0.  Thanks.

Comment: Apologies... the behavior I originally described Is the behavior I was getting prior to my last change.  Currently what's happening is that only one thread is getting created in the pool, and requests from the kafka topic are being run serially on that one thread.  I still need help figuring out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your topic has only one partition, according the consumer group policy, only one consumer is able to poll that partition.

The `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` indeed creates as much target `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` instances as provided `concurrency`. And it does that only in case it doesn't know the number of partitions in the topic.

When the rebalance in consumer group happens only one consumer gets partition for consuming. All the work is really done there in a single thread:

```
 private void startInvoker() {
    ListenerConsumer.this.invoker = new ListenerInvoker();
    ListenerConsumer.this.listenerInvokerFuture = this.containerProperties.getListenerTaskExecutor()
            .submit(ListenerConsumer.this.invoker);
}
```

One partition - one thread for sequential records processing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This seems like incorrect behavior to me.  I get that a partition can only have one consumer in a given group and that if I'm going to take the listener off the consumer thread and handle it myself that I have to deal with the ack on my own.  What I don't get is why the threading of the listeners has to be so closely tied to the threading of the consumers.  Spring has already made a distinction between consumer threads and listener threads, so why can't I set up as many listener threads as I want  even if I can only have one consumer thread based on my partitioning?

Comment: Well, Spring Kafka would like to be as close to Apache Kafka solution as possible. The current version has that thread shifting from consumer thread to listener thread because of lack of proper heart-beat. In the under development version `2.0` we have removed already listener thread and do all the processing directly in the consumer thread - the heart-beat has been fixed in Kafka. We do that just because that is Apache Kafka recommendation. You are feel free to have any threading model downstream the listener. That is already not `KafkaListenerContainer` responsibility to complicate things.

Comment: Fair enough.  I think, then, the answer is simply "You can't do that" which is a fine answer, even if it's not the one i wanted to hear.  Thanks again.